# Weird component lifecycle with react router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have this route (simplified)

```
<Route 
  path="/foo/:id">
  render={({match}) => (
    <Page key={match.params.id} id={match.params.id}/>
  )}
</Route>
```

Now the reason for that is that when I go from `/foo/1` to `/foo/2` I don't want to clear and update state of an existing component, it's too complex in my case. So I have a dynamic key which causes to unmount the `/foo/1` component and mount a brand new `/foo/2` component.

So far so good. But here is the catch. The lifecycle I observed is this

1. `/foo/1` re-render
2. `/foo/2` constructor
3. `/foo/2` componentDidMount
4. `/foo/1` componentWillUnmount
5. `/foo/2` render

Why doesn't the first component unmount before the second one mounts? Because of that I get weird re-renders and glitches (it's connected to redux store and initialization of the `/foo/2` component changes the store which manages to re-render still existing component `/foo/1`). Any ideas how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Very interesting. What happens if you put the `Page` inside the `render` prop instead? `<Route path="/foo/:id" render={({ match }) => <Page key={match.params.id} id={match.params.id}/>} />`

Comment: @Tholle I updated the question. I wrote it from top of my head, incorrectly. It was in the render as you describe, sorry for that. So it behaves badly even with the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to determine exactly what is happening with your short snippet of code, but, I believe your issues are relating to some anti-patterns;

A react component constructor should only be used for two things:

1. Initialising local state
2. Binding event handlers

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Secondly you are using the `render` prop with a inline function, this means when ever a matching route is detected and the parent component re-renders it will re-construct the component, un-mounting it first then mounting it again. To prevent this you should be defining the render function outside of the parents render function.

Thirdly because you have a dynamic route `/foo/:id` and assigning the value of `:id` to the key of the child component react sees it as a different component and doesn't unmount it until the current render process has reached the `un-mounting` stage. This means that for a short period of time you have `<Page key={1} />` & `<Page key={2}/>` present.

Because these three issues, you are getting what seems to be a weird component lifecycle but in fact it is react doing exactly what you told it to do.

**The Solution:**

1. Move the redux action being invoked in the constructor of the `<Page />` to be in the `componentDidMount()` function.
2. Move the inline render function to be outside the parent render function.
3. Remove the `key` prop.

Comment: Thanks , that helped